# Create dynamic object from given class reference and add values from list to it

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, excel-interop

I need to define method 'CreateClassInstance()' which take class reference as parameter. Based on given class reference, it creates dynamic class instance and at run time assign values from list. for testing purpose I have define TempUser class and in reality it can be any class. My purpose is I give class reference and excel file, and it return map object with excel data.

I have written Activator.CreateInstance which does create instance of class but I struggling to add values in created instance object.

### TestClass

```
public class TempUser
{
    public string CollarID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public void processRequest()
{
  CreateClassInstance<TempUser>()
}
```

..

```
public void CreateClassInstance<T>()
{
  Type ReceiveClasstype = typeof(T);
  T newObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

   //need help here to create object and add values to it.
    ?????????????????
}
```

This is equivalent I want under above CreateClassInstance method

```
List<TempUser> TempUserListObject = new List<TempUser>();
List<string> TempObjectDataList = new List<string>();

for (int i = ReadExcelRowFrom; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        if (j == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("\r\n");
        }

        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
        {
            TempObjectDataList.Add(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());



            Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
        }
        else
        {
            TempObjectDataList.Add("");
        }

    }

    TempUserListObject.Add(new TempUser()
    {
        CollarID = TempObjectDataList[0],
        Email = TempObjectDataList[1],
        IMEI = TempObjectDataList[2],
        Forename = TempObjectDataList[3],
        Surname = TempObjectDataList[4],
        Station = TempObjectDataList[5],
        Rank = TempObjectDataList[6],
        Department = TempObjectDataList[7],
        Division = TempObjectDataList[8],
        Area = TempObjectDataList[9],
        SupCollarID = TempObjectDataList[10],
        AccessRights = TempObjectDataList[11]
     });
    TempObjectDataList.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `GetProperty` method of the type to get a `PropertyInfo` and then call the `SetValue` method of this one to set the property of a specific instance, e.g.:

```
public void CreateClassInstance<T>()
{
    Type ReceiveClasstype = typeof(T);
    T newObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    //set the CollarId property of newObject:
    var property = ReceiveClasstype.GetProperty("CollarID ");
    property.SetValue(newObject, "collar id value...");
}
```

Of course you will need to know the name of the property that you want to set.

You could get the `PropertyInfo` of all public properties of a type using the `GetProperties` method:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertInfos = ReceiveClasstype.GetProperties();
```